# CQLSH Connecting to server

Tags: database, macos, cassandra, server, cqlsh

On my CQLSH command line I tried to login with my ID and password given by the university:

```
cqlsh> cqlsh -u username -p password  whatever.university.ca;
```

But somehow it's not connecting. I was told by the provider that I should be able to connect to the database this way from my university server. But I wasn't. Can anyone please help on this? By the way, I installed Cassandra before starting cqlsh. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell without the actual error message.

Comment: To Aaron's point, we need an error message. That being said, Are you trying to connect to a university cluster from your local machine? If so, you need to specify a contact point: cqlsh <ip address> -u username -p password

Comment: Sorry, the error msg I got was something like this: SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'cqlsh' ([cqlsh]...)">